# Why i can't use variable on for loop in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I use VueJS (in Laravel) to perform simple loop with variable's value.

Here, value comes from the template props.

**HTML:**

```
 <template id="segment" t_nb=2></template>


 <div id="test_loop">
  <b>@{{ t_nb }}</b>
  <div v-for="a in t_nb">
    <seg>@{{ a }}</seg>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**VueJS:**

```
Vue.component(
 'seg', {
    template: '#segment',
    props: ['t_nb']
      }
   );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 <!-- (Empty)-->
```

Here, i cant get loop for 2 times.

If i pass value of "**t_nb**" as 2 in direct manner like,

```
 <div v-for="a in 2">
    <seg>@{{ a }}</seg>
  </div>
```

then, i get **OUTPUT** as,

```
 1
 2
```

But i pass same value on both, vuejs only accepts the direct assignment.

Whats wrong with my code ?

How is this possible or any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i find out my mistake.

Here, the loop having trouble to find it's datatype.

```
  <div v-for="a in t_nb">
    <seg>@{{ a }}</seg>
  </div>
```

to

```
  <div v-for="a in parseInt(t_nb)">
    <seg>@{{ a }}</seg>
  </div>
```

Now its works charm.

Issue is to specify the Datatype.

Thank to @saurabh.

Thank You all !

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify your  **t_nb props** as an array, eg:

`props: {
    't_nb': {
        type: Array,
        default: [1, 2], // Value that you want to loop
    }
}`

And, then if you want to assign a new value for t_nb props, do:

`<seg :t_nb="[3,4,5,6]"></seg>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two things wrong with your code.

First thing: You  have to include you HTML in the template, as following. As you component `seg` is taking template `'#segment'`, it has to enclose all the relevant HTML.

```
<template id="segment">

   <div id="test_loop">
    <b>@{{ t_nb }}</b>
    <div v-for="a in t_nb">
      <seg>@{{ a }}</seg>
    </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Second thing:  You have to pass [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props): `t_nb=2` where you are rendering `seg` component, it should be like following:

```
<seg tn_b=2></seg>
```

Comment: but, why not variable ?

Comment: because [v-for](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for) searches the variables used inside vue instance. You are also having `t_nb` as props.